# laravel 4 routes with ?_escaped_fragment_=

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-4

I am trying to enable clean urls with Angular JS inside my Laravel 4 app. When I tried the required thing normally without laravel 4 refering to this url.

http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html, I was able to get the thing to work. Even `?_escaped_fragment_=` was changed to *snapshot/** folder and picked the content.

But I am not able to do the same in Laravel 4. I am not sure how to do this.

I am trying to define a route like `?_escaped_fragment_=/*` and redirect it to some controller but that doesn't work.

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Escaped fragment is a query parameter, not a route, there for, in the root route `Route::get('/', 'RootCtrl');`, you can check for `$_GET['_escaped_fragment']` presence, and if it is there, return an `HTTP 302` redirect to the corresponding file in the snapshots dir.

While this will work, it is not the perfect solution, since some bots might index the path of the `snapshots` file instead of the original one, and since doing it using the Laravel framework is not correct in the first place.

The best choice of course, is to rewrite any request that contains an `_escaped_fragment_`
query parameter to it's corresponding path, in the nginx\apache configuration, prior to the configuration of your Laravel app, this way those requests won't event reach the Laravel router.

I have co-authored an Angular [SEO plug-and-play solution](https://github.com/BeOleg/angular-seo), using PhantomJS & Mongoose integrated web server, to pre-render any Async JS code, and server it as raw HTML.

The server configuration aspects are also explained in the `README.md` file, please note that if you would like to use static snapshots, just change proxy-pass to rewrite(in order for the right URL to get indexed by the bots).

Hope that helps.

Example using simple rewrites with nginx:

```
if ($args ~* "^_escaped_fragment_=(.+)") {
        set $path $1
        set $args '';
        rewrite ^.*$ /snapshots/$path last;

 }
```

EDIT:

Apache, for your request (some words of advice: move to nginx).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment=(.+)$
  RewriteRule ^.*$ /snapshots/%1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried it... but I am not using PhantomJS and thus... I m not sure how I can fit this in my current requirement. :(